# Break and Continue in OpenCL kernel

Tags: c, opencl

How does one implement these within OpenCL kernel? Is 'return;' equivalent to 'break;'?

I am using openCL 1.2

I want to implement this with 3 nested for loops that cycle through a typedef struct of nested arrays.

**EDIT**

Realised I need to show some code to be better understood

IN KERNEL...

```
typedef struct tag_sfextras
{
    float *high;
    float *low;
}sfextras;

typedef struct tag_sdirection
{
    int time;
    float result;
    sfextras *fextras;
}sdirection;

__kernel void Call(sdirection *_direction,
                   int _index,
                   int _start,
                   int _stop,
                   __global float *_result)
{

    float _sum = 0.0f;

    if (_index > 1)
    {
        _result[0] = 0.0f;

        int i = get_global_id(0);

        if (_direction[i].time >= _stop)
        {
            break;//or return?...                     
        }

        if (_direction[i].time < _start)
        {
            continue;// what to put here?...          
        }
        else
        {
            _start = _direction[i].time + (1440 * 60);
        }

        int d = get_global_id(1);
        int f = get_global_id(2);

        float _fextras_weight = 0.0f;// need to zeroize on each inner loop (for f)

        _fextras_weight += (float)pow(_direction[_index - 1].fextras[d].high[f] - _direction[i].fextras[d].high[f], 2.0f);
        _fextras_weight += (float)pow(_direction[_index - 1].fextras[d].low[f] - _direction[i].fextras[d].low[f], 2.0f);

        _result[0] += _fextras_weight*_direction[i].result;
        _sum += _fextras_weight;

    }

    if (_sum > 0.0f)
    {
        _result[0] /= _sum;
    }
}
```

IN HOST (the code I am trying to replicate in kernel for efficiency)

```
            if(_direction_index > 1)
          {
              _fextras = 0.0f;
              for(int i=0;i<_direction_index-1;i++)
                {
                    if(_direction[i].time >= _stop)
                      {
                          break;
                      }

                    if(_direction[i].time < _start)
                      {
                          continue;
                      }
                    else
                      {
                          _direction_start = _direction[i].time + (1440*60);
                      }

                    for(int d=0;d<_DIRECTION;d++)
                      {
                          for(int f=0;f<_FEXTRAS;f++)
                            {
                                float _fextras_weight = 0.0f;

                                _fextras_weight += (float)pow(_direction[_direction_index-1].fextras[d].high[f]-_direction[i].fextras[d].high[f],2.0f);
                                _fextras_weight += (float)pow(_direction[_direction_index-1].fextras[d].low[f]-_direction[i].fextras[d].low[f],2.0f);

                                _fextras += _fextras_weight*_direction[i].result;
                                _sum += _fextras_weight;
                            }
                      }
                }

               if(_sum > 0.0f)
                 {
                    _fextras /= _sum;
                 }
          }
```

Comment: *(as always)* ***Show Code***

Comment: Suggest you read a book on C and lookup break, return and goto (goto is allowed to break out of nested loops, no matter what anybody says).

Comment: @PaulOgilvie have you done this in openCL __kernel?

Comment: Your question is about C.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie not really... openCL 1.2

Comment: @abelenky I have added code for both the kernel and the host. Please take a look.

Comment: Functions should not have a final `;` after the last `}`.

Comment: @abelenky that was typo...

Answer (score 2):

Canceling all other threads of opencl would make them undefined behaviour because many of them could be in the middle of writing/reading global/local memory and that could also purge the thread running(stop all other/remaining kernels/threads). Probably thats why there is no such thing in opencl.

But you can add an output array that each thread writes its last state. If an element has "return" code, you should check for "after_return" code to ommit those results' calculations results and accept "before_return" ones. This would also need atomic operations at the output stage so becomes slower which is bad.

But you can safely return from individual kernels:

Below code compiled well and early-quitted(ended kernel execution for some threads but not all) by the 'return' on a HD7870 and a R7-240 without error because 'return' is not one of the constraints applied by OpenCL.

```
__kernel void rarToVideo(__global int * p,__global char * c)
            {
              ...
                            if (tmp)
                            {
                                foo=1;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                return;
                            }

             ...
            }
```

Used opencl 1.2 headers of c++.

But, if you still need fake-return and a thread doesnt affect other threads' outputs/inputs, then something like this would help:

```
  // beginning phase of this thread
  if(globalAtomicElement[0]>=RETURNED)
  {
      // finished this thread so it doesn't waste ALU/LD-ST/....
      // leaves room for other wavefronts at least
      outputState[threadId]=NOT_STARTED;
      return;
  }
   ...
    ...
  // ending phase of this thread
  // localState has information if this thread needed a "return"
  // 0=NOT_RETURNED
  // 1=RETURNED
  // 2=NOT_STARTED
  lastResult=atomic_add(globalAtomicElement,localState);
  if(lastResult>=RETURNED)
  {
       outputState[threadId]=AFTER_RETURNED; // you ommit 
                                             // this thread's result 
                                             // because an other thread
                                             // pretends to stop all

        // so this thread wasted cycles but dont worry,
        // it would always waste even if you don't use
        // a core for GCN 1.0 - GCN 3.0 architectures
        // a core always spin within a compute unit if a 
        // core/shader is working on something.
        // polaris architecture will have ability
        // to shut down unused cores so that will not be
        // a problem of power consumption either. 
  }
  else if(lastResult==NOT_RETURNED && thisThreadReturned)
  {
       outputState[threadId]=RETURNED; // this is returning
                                       // thread
                                       //(finishing,pretending to stop all)
  }
  else if(lastResult==NOT_RETURNED && !thisThreadReturned)
  {
       outputState[threadId]=BEFORE_RETURNED; // you accept this thread's
                                              // results because no thread
                                              // has ever stopped and this
                                              // thread surely computed
                                              //everything before that
  }
```

then in host side, you check/filter-in only results of "BEFORE_RETURNED" and "RETURNED" and elliminate results of "AFTER_RETURNED".

In opencl 2.0, you can try this:

- start with 1 thread
- return? no= spawn 2 threads, yes= stop
- recursively compute: return? no=spawn 2 threads, yes=stop
- recursively finish all work

this could save half of threads at least (or 1/4 or 1/8 ... or 1/N) but would be slow since only 2 threads are inefficient.

Comment: thanks a lot for your attempt but I was looking more for a solution without loops in the kernel. Please see my edit above

Comment: Then you want to end "all remaining-pending threads" instead of just the current thread?

Comment: @ssn Then you need opencl 2.0. Start 1 thread, spawn more recursively or somethingelsely within the kernel, then when something needs return, invalidate other threads' results using some byte array or something.  Stopping new thread generation and checking which element "return"ed first, invalidate the remaining. But maybe opencl 2.0 has something fits this idk. You can try atomic functions in opencl 1.2 to control if any thread has finished before. This is a performance hit since you are doing that serially.

Comment: @ssn you should look at updated answer. There is something that may help. I can benchmark that end script if you need.